# Speed in for loops

Tags: r, data.table

With the data set here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyimxbz5f3v0uq3/kfg.RData?dl=0

And executing the below code:

```
matrix(nrow=1600,ncol=8) -> ctw
for(k in 1:8){
  for(i in 1:1600){
    which(kfg[,9]==i) -> aj
    if(length(aj)!=0){
      sample(kfg[aj,11],prob=kfg[aj,k],size=1) -> ctw[i,k]
    }
    ctw[i,k]
  }
}
```

Is doable, but the real set is over 800k rows and it takes very long. Is there a way in `data.table` or other package to do this faster? It is very slow to do the `which()` step.

Comment: You could check out apply. You could also use kfg[,9]==i instead of which, and instead of length(aj)!=0 then you need to use if(any(aj)). Using a vector of TRUE and FALSE values in aj achieves the same as using a vector of indeces. Don't know if it is faster because there is not enough data for me to test (your code is very fast on my machine).

Comment: I made a test with 800k rows, it does not take time at all. You should probably provide your complete dataset.

Answer (score 4):

I had to revise your original code to check for non-zero probabilities. I also removed the statement `ctw[i,k]` from the last line of the inner loop, because it has no effect. Your code is

```
matrix(nrow=1600,ncol=8) -> ctw
for(k in 1:8){
    for(i in 1:1600){
        which(kfg[,9]==i) -> aj
        if ((length(aj)!=0) && any(kfg[aj, k] > 0)) {
            sample(kfg[aj,11],prob=kfg[aj,k],size=1) -> ctw[i,k]
        }
    }
}
ctw
```

I reversed the order of the loops, so that `kfg[,9] == i` is only evaluated once instead of 8 times. I also took the test for `length(aj) != 0` outside the loops using `tabulate()`. My revised code is

```
matrix(nrow=1600,ncol=8) -> ctw
which(tabulate(kfg[, 9], 1600) != 0) -> ii
for(i in ii) {
    kfg[,9] == i -> aj
    for(k in 1:8)
        if (any(kfg[aj, k] > 0))
            sample(kfg[aj,11], 1, prob=kfg[aj,k]) -> ctw[i,k]
}
ctw
```

This is approximately 5x faster for your sample data.

It is much faster to extract the vector of sample values `kfg[,11] == kfg[[11]]` once, and to work with a matrix `as.matrix(kfg[, 1:8])` of probabilities, rather than a data.frame. For the sample data it is marginally faster to hoist the split on column 9 out of the loop, and to avoid the conditional inside the k loop by doing a vectorized calculation outside the loop to identify relevant indices

```
nrow <- 1600
matrix(nrow=nrow,ncol=8) -> ctw
x <- kfg[[11]]
pr <- as.matrix(kfg[,1:8])
ajs <- split(seq_len(nrow(kfg)), factor(kfg[[9]], levels=seq_len(nrow)))
ii <- seq_along(ajs)[lengths(ajs) > 0]
for(i in ii) {
    aj <- ajs[[i]]
    kk <- which(colSums(pr[aj,, drop=FALSE]) > 0)
    for(k in kk)
        sample(x[aj], 1, prob=pr[aj,k]) -> ctw[i,k]
}
ctw
```

These lead to a further 5x speed-up, so 25 times faster than the original.

To measure the speed, I enclosed each of the above in a function, e.g.,

```
f0 <- function() {
    matrix(nrow=1600,ncol=8) -> ctw
    for(k in 1:8){
        for(i in 1:1600){
            which(kfg[,9]==i) -> aj
            if ((length(aj)!=0) && any(kfg[aj, k] > 0)) {
                sample(kfg[aj,11],prob=kfg[aj,k],size=1) -> ctw[i,k]
            }
        }
     }
    ctw
}
```

and used the microbenchmark package

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f0(), f1(), f2(), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 f0() 466.12527 483.43954 484.34258 483.74805 484.21627 521.19957    10   c
 f1()  92.77415  94.79052  94.99273  95.10352  95.45368  96.10641    10  b 
 f2()  17.33708  17.83257  17.87095  17.87205  18.01723  18.16400    10 a
```

`f1()` and `f2()` should be identical, but they are not

```
> set.seed(123); res1 <- f1(); set.seed(123); res2 <- f2()
> all.equal(res1, res2)
[1] "'is.NA' value mismatch: 12096 in current 12133 in target"
```

Investigating, this is because the values in column 9 are numeric, but are treated, e.g., `kfg[, 9] == i` as though they are integer. For instance,

```
> kfg[[9]][(kfg[[9]] > 28 & kfg[[9]] <= 29)]
[1] 29 29 29
> kfg[[9]][(kfg[[9]] > 28 & kfg[[9]] <= 29)] == 29
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Perhaps the intention is

```
kfg[[9]] = round(kfg[[9]])
```

With this change, we have

```
> all.equal(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE
> identical(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE
```